# Retry will not continue if before/aftermethod is failed or skipped in testNG?

Tags: java, testng

I code the retry mechanism by implements the IRetryAnalyzer. And just found out, if the beforemethod/aftermethod got exception, the retry mechanism will not work, is that working as design or my code issue?

```
   public class MyRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
  public static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;

  // to avoid the thread safe issue, use the AtomicInteger class, instead of Integer
  AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

  public boolean isRetryAvailable() {
    return (count.intValue() > 0);
  }

  /**
   * retry a failed test
   *
   * @param ITestResult result - the test result of current test case
   * 
   * @return Returns true if the test method has to be retried, false otherwise.
   * 
   * @author Fiona Zhang
   */

  @Override
  public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    boolean retry = false;
    System.out.println("result status is : ------------------------- "+result.getStatus());
    if (isRetryAvailable()) {
      System.out.println("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", "
          + (MAX_RETRY_COUNT - count.intValue() + 1) + " out of " + MAX_RETRY_COUNT);
      retry = true;
      // --count
      count.decrementAndGet();
    }
    return retry;
  }
}
```

Comment: Anybody notice this question...?

Comment: Could you open an issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/ ?

Comment: Done, please check it, https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1444